# Creating musicXML browser in IOS using LibMusicXML

Tags: ios, musicxml

LibMusicXML: does anyone have any examples of using this library in an IOS project? Would like to use it to view music scores in musicXML format.

Advice on adding a C++ library and how to display musicXML using this library in IOS would be appreciated?

Answer (score 3):

From searching around - there appears to be this code base AscoGraph https://github.com/k4rm/AscoGraph